# Getting error while applying Glide dependency

Tags: android, android-webservice

> *Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0**

Show in File

Show in Project Structure dialog

I am using android studio version 2.3.2

Comment: Hi, please update the code which you have tried. No one gets any idea just seeing the error.

Comment: I am sorry if you didn't understood. But other guys who have answered have understood and resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try different version

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

OR

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you, compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

add your  Gradle

```
repositories {
mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
}
```

Or Maven:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.bumptech.glide</groupId>
<artifactId>glide</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0-RC0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
<artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
<version>r7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupdId>com.github.bumptech.glide</groupId>
<artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0-RC0</version>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Getting 2 errors now 1(Error:Failed to resolve: annotationProcessor
Open File) 2( Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0
Show in FileShow in Project Structure dialog)